# Watson Assitant Search Skill beta

Tags: watson-assistant

I was hoping I could get some help or someone to point me in the right direction for support. I am trying to use the search skill beta feature (Watson Discovery Integration. I have created a chatbot and discovery service from the instructions at this link (https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-skill-search-add#skill-search-add). Everything seems to run fine, when I click on the "Try it" inside my search skill. for example, when I type "sauvignon blanc" the chat bot searchs discovery and come back with the correct result.
https://slack-files.com/T0A2350NL-FJ88ALAKH-90b286553b

when I try it through the preview link it just hangs
https://slack-files.com/T0A2350NL-FJ88ALAKH-90b286553b

when I ask the browser to "Stop it" it comes back that it is searching the discovery but does not come back with a response
https://slack-files.com/T0A2350NL-FHUV1HD5H-e5e215940e

Answer (score 1):

I take it that when you say it works in the Try-it panel - the results you see are within the "card" format. If this is correct, then you sounds like you have configured the search skill element correct.

With regards to the dialog element, I take it that you have configured a dialog node with the search-skill rich response (or the anything else node). What have you put in the configured sections of the search-skill? 
{ the doc's could be wrong here, by default the complete input text is passed to the search-skill, but the doc's say you need to add "" in the query element of the configure box.

Finally have you connected the preview assistant to both your dialog and search skill - i.e. does it show as linked in both skills.